# Python - Check if a word is in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

How to tell if a word is in a string?

- Words are not sub-strings.
- I don't want to use regex.

Using only `in` is not enough...

Something like:

```
>>> wordSearch('sea', 'Do seahorses live in reefs?')
False
>>> wordSearch('sea', 'Seahorses live in the open sea.')
True
```

- Note 1: 'sea' and 'seahorses' are different words.
- Note 2: Binding punctuation can cause troubles.
- Note 3: The question in [How do I check if a sentence contains a certain word in Python and then perform an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897942/how-do-i-check-if-a-sentence-contains-a-certain-word-in-python-and-then-perform)
  **is not the same** question here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Check If Word Is In A String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string) or else (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897942/how-do-i-check-if-a-sentence-contains-a-certain-word-in-python-and-then-perform)

Comment: @Kevin, no, it doesn't. Different question, different problem, different answer.

Comment: why did you post the same answer on one of the other questions I flagged this as being a duplicate of then? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453803/5517088

Comment: I posted my solution there because the accepted solution is, at least, incomplete. Check it to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about to split the string and strip words punctuation, without forget the case?

```
w in [ws.strip(',.?!') for ws in p.split()]
```

Maybe that way:

```
def wordSearch(word, phrase):
    punctuation = ',.?!'
    return word in [words.strip(punctuation) for words in phrase.split()]

    # Attention about punctuation (here ,.?!) and about split characters (here default space)
```

Sample:

```
>>> print(wordSearch('Sea'.lower(), 'Do seahorses live in reefs?'.lower()))
False
>>> print(wordSearch('Sea'.lower(), 'Seahorses live in the open sea.'.lower()))
True
```

I moved the case transformation to the function call to simplify the code...
And I didn't check performances.

Comment: a word is in a string could be giving true for the first example

Answer (score 1):

Use the `in` keyword:

something like this:

`print('Sea'in 'Seahorses live in the open sea.')`

If you don't want it to be case sensitive. convert all the sting to `lower` or `upper`

something like this:

```
string1 = 'allow'
string2 = 'Seahorses live in the open sea Allow.'

print(string1.lower() in string2.lower())
```

or you may use the `find` method like this:

```
string1 = 'Allow'
string2 = 'Seahorses live in the open sea Allow.'

if string2.find(string1) !=-1 :
    print('yes')
```

If you want to match the exact word:

```
string1 = 'Seah'
string2 = 'Seahorses live in the open sea Allow.'

a = sum([1 for x in string2.split(' ') if x == string1])

if a > 0:
    print('Yes')

else:
    print('No')
```

**update**

you need to ignore all the punctuation so use this.

```
def find(string1, string2):
    lst = string2.split(' ')
    puctuation = [',', '.', '!']
    lst2 = []
    
    for x in lst:
        for y in puctuation:
            if y in x[-1]:
                lst2.append(x.replace(y, ''))
        lst2.append(x)
    
    lst2.pop(-1)    
    a = sum([1 for x in lst2 if x.lower() == string1.lower()])
    if a > 0:
        print('Yes')
    
    else:
        print('No')

find('sea', 'Seahorses live in the open sea. .hello!')
```

Comment: The 'in' keyword looks for substrings too, so it will match seahorse too...
Not good...

Comment: @marcio which one?  the last one?

Comment: he means a word sorrounded by boundries, not a substring

Comment: @marcio note it's case sensitive.

Comment: @marcio it works perfectly fine for me what is the problem?

Comment: Try with:
`string1 = 'sea'`
`string2 = 'Seahorses live in the open sea.'`
The dot goes together in split...

Comment: @marcio check my edit and tell me if that works fine.

Comment: Yes, it works! BUT you're only testing ending right punctuation! It would be better remove left and right! And attention, your code start to be complicate! Good job!

Comment: @marcio just remove the [-1]  in `x[-1]`  there.  Also, if you found this helpful don't forget to accept the answer